# Buffer and cache Difference?

Tags: sql-server, windows

Can anybody detail - What is the difference between Buffer and Cache in system memory?

Answer (score 24):

A **buffer** is just a container to hold data for a short period of time when more comes in at any given time than a consumer can use / process. It's a first-in, first-out situation - the data comes in, might be buffered, and goes out in the same order it came in, after a while.

A **cache** is a storage for speeding up certain operations. Things get put in a cache, and should be retrieved from it multiple times, over and over again. There's no "flowing through the cache" kind of mechanism - data doesn't come in and go out in the same order - but it's just a holding container. The order might be anything, really - items are addressed via a key, they don't "flow through" but they are "put in" and stay there (until they're thrown out because of not being used, or because the system goes down).

Comment: but if cache is a temporary data holder, what is the difference between "cache" and "used"? These two parameters will be displayed if you use "free -m" or "dstat -m".

Answer (score 5):

A `buffer` is a contemporary collection of location where a huge amount of data is managed or disassembled. This may be basic for interaction with a set of collection device that needs huge blocks of information, or when data must be given in a many way than that in which it is made, or rarely considerable when less blocks are not sufficient. The advantage is here even if the buffered data are stored to the buffer in one time and get from the buffer once.

A `cache`, on the other side, thinks that the data will be get from the cache more one time than they are written on them. 
Its aim is to less the accesses to the underlying stock.
Buffer is a programmable cache managed by the operating system in the main storage and is used to have the most necessary data from disk, so that they don't have to be gotten again from the memory. This feature is available by the operating system. While cache is in real a hardware that the CPU uses to reduced the effective memory access time.

Answer (score 0):

Add something from [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)) about the difference between **Buffer** and **Cache**.

> A buffer is a temporary memory location that is traditionally used
>   because CPU instructions cannot directly address data stored in
>   peripheral devices. Thus, addressable memory is used as an
>   intermediate stage. Additionally, such a buffer may be feasible when a
>   large block of data is assembled or disassembled (as required by a
>   storage device), or when data may be delivered in a different order
>   than that in which it is produced. Also, a whole buffer of data is
>   usually transferred sequentially (for example to hard disk), so
>   buffering itself sometimes increases transfer performance or reduces
>   the variation or jitter of the transfer's latency as opposed to
>   caching where the intent is to reduce the latency. These benefits are
>   present even if the buffered data are written to the buffer once and
>   read from the buffer once.
>
> A cache also increases transfer performance. A part of the increase
>   similarly comes from the possibility that multiple small transfers
>   will combine into one large block. But the main performance-gain
>   occurs because there is a good chance that the same data will be read
>   from cache multiple times, or that written data will soon be read. A
>   cache's sole purpose is to reduce accesses to the underlying slower
>   storage. Cache is also usually an abstraction layer that is designed
>   to be invisible from the perspective of neighboring layers.

Answer (score -1):

A buffer is just like a drum it can hold data and flush it out ... On the other hand Cache is used to make your operations faster.