# What is the difference between buffer and cache memory in Linux?

Tags: linux, caching, memory, buffer

To me it's not clear what's the difference between the two Linux memory concepts : `buffer` and `cache`. I've read through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192579/buffer-and-cache-difference) and it seems to me  that the difference between them is the expiration policy:

1. buffer's policy is first-in, first-out
2. cache's policy is Least Recently Used.

Am I right?

In particular, I'm looking at the two commands: `free` and `vmstat`

```
james@utopia:~$ vmstat -S M
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ----cpu----
r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa
5  0      0    173     67    912    0    0    19    59   75 1087 24  4 71  1
james@utopia:~$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2007       1834        172          0         67        914
-/+ buffers/cache:        853       1153
Swap:         2859          0       2859
```

Comment: You might also visit http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 74, accepted):

"Buffers" represent how much portion of RAM is dedicated to cache disk blocks. "Cached" is similar like "Buffers", only this time it caches pages from file reading.

quote from:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20110207101856/http://www.linuxforums.org/articles/using-top-more-efficiently_89.html

Comment: I have tested this using a simple python program that writes large amounts of blocks. What happens is that the `cache` gets filled up as reported by `free -w -h`, not the `buffers` column. I think the `cache` column counts both disk writes and disk reads and `buffers` is used for something else.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai thanks for the experimental evidence. The interesting question is whether you were writing faster than the disk could flush out. (e.g. would sync take a long time) which would tell us if dirty blocks are counted differently than clean ones. Linux will certainly cache both types (lru as mentioned in the question) but one is far more serious in terms of memory pressure.

Answer (score 201):

> Buffers are associated with a specific block device, and cover caching
>   of filesystem metadata as well as tracking in-flight pages. The cache
>   only contains parked file data. That is, the buffers remember what's
>   in directories, what file permissions are, and keep track of what
>   memory is being written from or read to for a particular block device.
>   The cache only contains the contents of the files themselves.

[quote link](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/System/Linux%20Memory%20Management.htm)

Answer (score 90):

[Cited answer (for reference):](http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Buffers-and-Cached-columns-in-proc-meminfo-output)

> Short answer: Cached is the size of the page cache. Buffers is the size of in-memory block I/O buffers. Cached matters; Buffers is largely irrelevant.
>
> Long answer: Cached is the size of the Linux page cache, minus the memory in the swap cache, which is represented by SwapCached (thus the total page cache size is Cached + SwapCached). Linux performs all file I/O through the page cache. Writes are implemented as simply marking as dirty the corresponding pages in the page cache; the flusher threads then periodically write back to disk any dirty pages. Reads are implemented by returning the data from the page cache; if the data is not yet in the cache, it is first populated. On a modern Linux system, Cached can easily be several gigabytes. It will shrink only in response to memory pressure. The system will purge the page cache along with swapping data out to disk to make available more memory as needed.
>
> Buffers are in-memory block I/O buffers. They are relatively short-lived. Prior to Linux kernel version 2.4, Linux had separate page and buffer caches. Since 2.4, the page and buffer cache are unified and Buffers is raw disk blocks not represented in the page cache—i.e., not file data. The Buffers metric is thus of minimal importance. On most systems, Buffers is often only tens of megabytes.

Comment: "Buffers is largely irrelevant" - No. There are many cases, where file content caching is irrelevant, but keeping the metadata in cache speeds things up. A video streaming NAS server for instance.

Comment: Any system doing lots of I/O will use lots of memory for buffers. I'm bulkloading a 100GB MySQL/InnoDB database and buffers go above 2GB all the time.

Answer (score 26):

It's not 'quite' as simple as this, but it might help understand:

Buffer is for storing file metadata (permissions, location, etc). Every memory page is kept track of here.

Cache is for storing actual file contents.

Comment: IOW, Buffer = Metadata;  Cache = Data;

Answer (score 26):

Explained by **Red Hat**:

**Cache Pages:**

A cache is the part of the memory which transparently stores data so that future requests for that data can be served faster. This memory is utilized by the kernel to cache disk data and improve i/o performance.

The Linux kernel is built in such a way that it will use as much RAM as it can to cache information from your local and remote filesystems and disks. As the time passes over various reads and writes are performed on the system, kernel tries to keep data stored in the memory for the various processes which are running on the system or the data that of relevant processes which would be used in the near future. The cache is not reclaimed at the time when process get stop/exit, however when the other processes requires more memory then the free available memory, kernel will run heuristics to reclaim the memory by storing the cache data and allocating that memory to new process.

When any kind of file/data is requested then the kernel will look for a copy of the part of the file the user is acting on, and, if no such copy exists, it will allocate one new page of cache memory and fill it with the appropriate contents read out from the disk.

The data that is stored within a cache might be values that have been computed earlier or duplicates of original values that are stored elsewhere in the disk. When some data is requested, the cache is first checked to see whether it contains that data. The data can be retrieved more quickly from the cache than from its source origin.

SysV shared memory segments are also accounted as a cache, though they do not represent any data on the disks. One can check the size of the shared memory segments using ipcs -m command and checking the bytes column.

**Buffers:**

Buffers are the disk block representation of the data that is stored under the page caches. Buffers contains the metadata of the files/data which resides under the page cache.
Example: When there is a request of any data which is present in the page cache, first the kernel checks the data in the buffers which contain the metadata which points to the actual files/data contained in the page caches. Once from the metadata the actual block address of the file is known, it is picked up by the kernel for processing.

Comment: Do you have a source from Red Hat for this content?

Answer (score 11):

buffer and cache.

A buffer is something that has yet to be "written" to disk.

A cache is something that has been "read" from the disk and stored for later use.

Comment: new user tip: make your answer as clearly relate to the question as possible. If I were you, I'd add to your answer a section starting with "So, with your example..." and elaborate a little on that.

Comment: I don't think this answer is true in the same context as that of the question (namely, what the Linux kernel means by "buffer" and "cache"

Answer (score 8):

I think this page will help understanding the difference between buffer and cache deeply. http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/buffer-cache.html

Reading from a disk is very slow compared to accessing (real) memory. In addition, it is common to read the same part of a disk several times during relatively short periods of time. For example, one might first read an e-mail message, then read the letter into an editor when replying to it, then make the mail program read it again when copying it to a folder. Or, consider how often the command `ls` might be run on a system with many users. By reading the information from disk only once and then keeping it in memory until no longer needed, one can speed up all but the first read. This is called disk buffering, and the memory used for the purpose is called the buffer cache.

Since memory is, unfortunately, a finite, nay, scarce resource, the buffer cache usually cannot be big enough (it can't hold all the data one ever wants to use). When the cache fills up, the data that has been unused for the longest time is discarded and the memory thus freed is used for the new data.

Disk buffering works for writes as well.    On the one hand, data that is written is often soon read again (e.g., a source code file is saved to a file, then read by the compiler), so putting data that is written in the cache is a good idea. On the other hand, by only putting the data into the cache, not writing it to disk at once, the program that writes runs quicker. The writes can then be done in the background, without slowing down the other programs.

Comment: This explains what buffer cache is, but not what the difference is between buffer and cache in the outputs of the vmstat and free commands.

Answer (score 8):

Seth Robertson's Link 2 said "For thorough understanding of those terms, refer to Linux kernel book like Linux Kernel Development by Robert M. Love."

I found some contents about 'buffer' in the 2nd edition of the book.

> Although the physical device itself is addressable at the sector level, the kernel performs all disk operations in terms of blocks.
>
> When a block is stored in memory (say, after a read or pending a write), it is stored in a 'buffer'. Each 'buffer' is associated with exactly one block. The 'buffer' serves as the object that represents a disk block in memory.
>
> A 'buffer' is the in-memory representation of a single physical disk block.
>
> Block I/O operations manipulate a single disk block at a time. A common block I/O operation is reading and writing inodes. The kernel provides the bread() function to perform a low-level read of a single block from disk. Via 'buffers', disk blocks are mapped to their associated in-memory pages. "

Answer (score 7):

Quote from the book:
[Introduction to Information Retrieval](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521865719)

**Cache**

> We want to keep as much data as possible in memory, especially those data that we need to access frequently. We call the technique of keeping frequently used disk data in main memory caching.

**Buffer**

> Operating systems generally read and write entire blocks. Thus, reading a single byte from disk can take as much time as reading the entire block. Block sizes of 8, 16, 32, and 64 kilobytes (KB) are common. We call the part of main memory where a block being read or written is stored a buffer.

Answer (score 5):

**Buffer** is an area of memory used to temporarily store data while it's being moved from one place to another.

**Cache** is a temporary storage area used to store frequently accessed data for rapid access. Once the data is stored in the cache, future use can be done by accessing the cached copy rather than re-fetching the original data, so that the average access time is shorter.

Note: buffer and cache can be allocated on disk as well

Comment: > moved from one place to another. Do you mean that this data was read from disk and now is being written to someplace else?

Answer (score 2):

Buffer contains metadata which helps improve write performance

Cache contains the file content itself (sometimes yet to write to disk) which improves read performance

Answer (score 2):

For starters the general concept would be helpful, a buffer is an area of memory used to temporarily store data while being moved from one place to another. On the other hand, a cache is a temporary storage area to store frequently accessed data for rapid access.

In Linux:
The cache in Linux is called Page Cache. It is that certain amount of system memory that the kernel reserves for caching the file system disk accesses. This is to make overall performance faster. During Linux read system calls, the kernel checks if the cache contains the requested blocks of data. If it does, then that would be a successful cache hit. The cache returns this data without doing any I/O to the disk system. The Linux cache approach is called a write-back cache. This means first, the data is written to cache memory and marked as dirty until synchronized to disk. Then, the kernel maintains the internal data structure to optimize which data to evict from the cache when the cache demands any additional space. For example, when memory usage reaches certain thresholds, background tasks start writing dirty data to disk, thereby emptying the memory cache.
Reading from a disk is very slow compared to accessing (real) memory. In addition, it is common to read the same part of a disk several times during relatively short periods of time. For example, one might first read an e-mail message, then read the letter into an editor when replying to it, then make the mail program read it again when copying it to a folder. Or, consider how often the command ls might be run on a system with many users. By reading the information from disk only once and then keeping it in memory until no longer needed, one can speed up all but the first read. This is called disk buffering, and the memory used for the purpose is called the buffer cache.

Answer (score 0):

Cache: This is a place acquired by kernel on physical RAM to store pages in caches. Now we need some sort of index to get the address of pages from caches. Here we need the buffer for page caches which keeps metadata of page cache.

Answer (score -1):

From the man page for `free`:

```
DESCRIPTION
       free  displays  the  total amount of free and used physical and swap memory in the system, as well as the buffers and caches used by the
       kernel. The information is gathered by parsing /proc/meminfo. The displayed columns are:

       total  Total installed memory (MemTotal and SwapTotal in /proc/meminfo)

       used   Used memory (calculated as total - free - buffers - cache)

       free   Unused memory (MemFree and SwapFree in /proc/meminfo)

       shared Memory used (mostly) by tmpfs (Shmem in /proc/meminfo)

       buffers
              Memory used by kernel buffers (Buffers in /proc/meminfo)

       cache  Memory used by the page cache and slabs (Cached and SReclaimable in /proc/meminfo)

       buff/cache
              Sum of buffers and cache

       available
              Estimation of how much memory is available for starting new applications, without swapping. Unlike the data provided by the cache
              or  free fields, this field takes into account page cache and also that not all reclaimable memory slabs will be reclaimed due to
              items being in use (MemAvailable in /proc/meminfo, available on kernels 3.14, emulated on kernels 2.6.27+, otherwise the same  as
              free)
```