# differences between cached and buffered memory on Linux

Tags: linux, memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linux memory: buffer vs cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345020/linux-memory-buffer-vs-cache)

When using command like ps/free to monitor memory on a Linux box, we can see a statistic called buffered memory and another called cached memory. I have searched Internet but cannot find a consistent answer for their differences. Appreciate if anyone could give me any hints.

BTW: I am debugging a program's memory usage pattern, so understanding the concepts are useful for my development.

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: I searched before asking this question. But I cannot find out what are exactly the differences between this statement -- "Buffers" represent how much portion of RAM is dedicated to cache disk block. "Cached" is similar like "Buffers", only this time it caches pages from file reading.". Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

Buffers are the I/O buffers whereas cached is the page cache.

Comment: Hi @Karunesh, what are the differences between I/O buffer and page cache? Appreciate if you could show an example?

Comment: Page cache is the cache of physical disk pages. It is used for file I/O. I/O buffers is a relatively smaller amount of memory used for input and output operations to devices. For example, the disk is also available as a block special file and one can manipulate a disk block at a time.

Comment: Thanks @Karunesh. It seems both page cache and buffer could be used in file I/O? What are the differences? Appreciate if you could give more comments.