# keeps filling up memory with cached

Tags: mysql, linux

I tried to clear cache but it keeps filling up the memory. I also decreased swappiness but no luck.

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-140 src]# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         34240      34080        159          0         12      32644
-/+ buffers/cache:       1423      32816
Swap:         2047          0       2047

836.0 KiB + 555.0 KiB =   1.4 MiB       bash (2)
  2.3 MiB + 325.5 KiB =   2.7 MiB       udevd (3)
  1.7 MiB +   1.9 MiB =   3.5 MiB       sshd (3)
  9.5 MiB +   3.3 MiB =  12.8 MiB       nginx (5)
 23.8 MiB + 700.0 KiB =  24.5 MiB       php
180.1 MiB + 356.5 KiB = 180.5 MiB       mysqld
760.9 MiB +   9.7 MiB = 770.6 MiB       php-fpm (14)
---------------------------------
                          1.0 GiB
```

I am using aws ami. How can i find the bottleneck of such writing on disk. i found that the disk is busy.

Comment: Let the cache use the memory - it is *supposed to*. Memory that isn't used is wasted memory. The cache will get "pushed out" if the memory is actually needed for important things. Anyway, this isn't a programming-related question - try on the appropriate Linux stack.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345020/linux-memory-buffer-vs-cache

Comment: (Or, is the question is *explicitly* about MySQL tuning options, then make sure that is clearly specified.)

Comment: So why is this a problem? Is there an issue you are facing?

Comment: This makes my server out of memory, and slows down the page.